# Calculate lots of pruned averages from a list from a CSV file using Python, pandas, and DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, average

I need to calculate a lot of averages from a list (that is from a CSV file) that I read in Python using pandas and DataFrame. That list is a list of numbers, floats, like 12.54, 10.20 or 7.49 (If you want to know, it's rubik's cube times, that I want to analyze, and so there comes the idea of making averages to improve and see my improvements everyday.)
What I want is a program that calculates every single average and that tells me which one is the best, with the values of the average.
But, my averages are quite different, because I need what we call a "pruned average" I think.
Basically, it's an average in which you take off the bests and the worsts times to get something more representative of your level (because in an average of rubik's cube, you can get lucky on a scramble, or mess up a solve)
For example, in an average of 5, or of 12, you'll need to take off the worst, and the best time.
In an average of 25, you'll need to take off 4 solves, the two bests and the two worsts.
In an average of 50, you'll need to take off 5 solves, the two bests and the three worsts.

To sum-up, I need a program that calculates all the averages, of a list, from a csv file, while taking off an amount of the values of each average, and I need that program to be customizable.
So the first average, if we take averages of 5, would be, from the value 0 to the value 4 of the list, then, the second one would be, from the value 1 to the value 5, and so on !

I'm not sure if there's a way to do all of that, but I hope you all will find something !

Comment: I think you will have to build up a program with multiple steps.  What you are calling "pruned average" is often called "trimmed mean".  Check out `scipy.stats.trim_mean`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a few lines from your CSV (in text format) and show what the required output would be.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I'll check all of what you said when I'll find time, and so I'll tell you the updates !